# QProcess Python, run a bash script

Tags: python, bash, conda, qprocess

I have a following bash script:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ann"
echo "Kasia"
source /home/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate my_environment
conda list
```

I want to run it using QtCore.QProcess. I tested the following configurations, unfortunately non of them printed results.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import  QtCore
process = QtCore.QProcess()
process.start("/bin/bash", ["-i", "-c", "script.sh"])

from PyQt5 import  QtCore
process = QtCore.QProcess()
process.start("script.sh")
```

The output is 'Process finished with exit code 0'

I expect it to be something like:

```
Ann
Kasia
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0
```

Comment: I want to admit that when I open terminal and type `./script.sh` it works fine and prints output

Answer (score 1):

`QProcess.start()` starts a process *asynchronously.* That means you probably want to call `waitForStarted()` and/or `waitForFinished()` to ensure it finishes before you carry on.